# Magento2.1.14: Css not loaded after upgrading apache 2.34 to 2.37

Tags: magento-2.1, css, https, apache

I have upgrade apache 2.34 to 2.37. Then I have the problem that all css and js files are only throwing a 500 error and are not loaded. I have got this error on error log:
**option followsymlinks not allowed here** 
I tried several times to deploy and compile those files and even set up 777 permissions on those files folders but have no luck to get it working.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace Options **+FollowSymLinks** to **+SymLinksIfOwnerMatch** in **.htaccess** file.

And run this command

```
find /home -name ".htaccess" -type f -exec sed -i 's/FollowSymLinks/SymLinksIfOwnerMatch/g' {} ";"
```

it solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you have URL rewrites enabled in your Apache config.
Here is a tutorial : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-rewrite-urls-with-mod_rewrite-for-apache-on-ubuntu-16-04

This is needed when 'sign static files' is enabled.
Also be sure that your allow/disallow settings in your apache site config are set to

```
 <Directory path/to/magento_root>
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add below piece of code in your apache config file.

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride Indexes
</Directory>
```

Adding only on .htaccess file sometimes will not work due to configuration ( AllowOverride None ) of apache config file.